# Sick [with/by] dengue

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct for this meaning(that the disease that "attacked" me was dengue)
▪︎ I tell my friend what the disease "attacked" me is by saying this, "I was sick [with/by] dengue."
I think "with" is correct.

Comment: SE English Language and Usage is "a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". Clearly a basic question on the use of prepositions does not fit here. We have a sister site, [SE English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com), for speakers of other languages learning English, where your question may be appropriate. But please check with a dictionary before posting.

Answer (score 1):

[Gio](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/264641/gio) provided information in a comment:

Sick is usually followed by preposition “with” to refer to an illness: https://m.freecollocation.com/browse/sick